# Inner product and ORTHOGONALITY

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, orthogonality

$W$ is a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^4$ (with usual inner product) spanned by $u=(2,1,-4, 0), v=(-1 ,-1 ,2 ,2), w=(3,2,5,4).$ if $z=(-34,a,-6,b)$ is in $W^\perp$ then $a+b=?$
Answer: $55$

Ok so I put the vectors in rows and found the null space after row reducing, but I don't know how to get the $z$ but I'm sure u have to use the null space some how...

Answer (score 0):

**HINT:** $<z,u>=0$, $<z,v>=0$

Answer (score 0):

Since $\mathbf{z} \in W^\perp$, we have that $\mathbf{z} \cdot \mathbf{u}=0, ~\mathbf{z}\cdot\mathbf{v}=0,$ and $ \mathbf{z}\cdot\mathbf{w}=0$. Thus $\mathbf{z}$ is in the null space of the matrix with $\mathbf{u}, \mathbf{v}, \mathbf{w}$ as rows.

Since $\mathbf{u},\mathbf{v}, \mathbf{w}$ are linearly independent, this matrix will have a one dimensional null space. We can then find a basis vector for the null space and note that $\bf{z}$ is a scalar multiple of this basis vector.

Alternatively, we can use that the dot products are all zero to generate a linear system of equations for the unknowns $a$ and $b$ and solve in whatever manner seems best.